# Typescript: Importing a module, causes a new module?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Actually I have two Typescript files:

app.ts:

```
import * as angular from "angular2/angular2";
angular.bootstrap(Hello);
```

and Hello.ts

```
import * as angular from "angular2/angular2";

@angular.Component({
     selector: "hello"
})
@angular.View({templateUrl: "hello.html"})
class Hello{


}
```

As soon, I used the import-statement in hello.ts, the class Hello got unknown in the app.ts so I had to import Hello:

```
import {Hello} from "Hello";
```

Does somebody know a workaround for this? I think it's pretty annoying, to import every single Class-File, which is using an import-statement

Ceddy

Comment: It may be annoying, but after you write a hundred page javascript application Not using modular design (the old way), you'll learn the downsides and be pleased to have the annoyance. This is an important concept known as "abstraction."

Comment: Yes you're right, but the need to import every singel script, by its complete relative path create also an unmaintainable code, every time I move a file, I have to change the path every Time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the ES6/CommonJS/AMD importing, you will want to do it everywhere, and you will need to import your dependencies wherever you need them.

Your app.ts should look like this:

```
import * as angular from "angular2/angular2";
import Hello from './Hello';

angular.bootstrap(Hello);
```

And your hello.ts should look like this:

```
import * as angular from "angular2/angular2";

@angular.Component({
     selector: "hello"
})
@angular.View({templateUrl: "hello.html"})
export default class Hello {


}
```

The `export default` tells TypeScript that the `Hello` class is the default export, so you don't need to do `import {Hello} from './Hello'`.